# Laptop MOBO repalcement or chip level replacement

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

My Samsung (NP300ESA-S05SA) laptops power ic is gone. Been working with that for almost 2 years by not using power saver mode and display brightness in full mode (Yeah this is my own temporary solution after so many trial and error method) .

Recently the temporary fix is no more working as the power ic is completely went bad. Still able to run in AC mode (another temporary fix ).

But I want to fix it permanently. Took it to Samsung service center and I was given two choice

1. Replace the MOBO for 140 US$ (Lot of money in India)
2. Replace the power ic using chip level for 55$

I am not sure of the chip level replacement. In which of these I can place my bet.

Both of these two solution gives 3 months warranty.

What to opt ? and why ?

Comment: I would question the diagnosis.  How does anyone know that the problem is that one chip and only that one chip?  There isn't a cost-effective way to manually troubleshoot a motherboard.  Is the warranty on the chip, itself, or the solution?  Personally, I wouldn't mess with locally repairing a motherboard.  The replacement board will be a refurbished one that should have been thoroughly tested (although sometimes the testing is done in the customer's computer during the warranty).

Comment: @fixer1234 so neither of them is a good fix ?

Comment: Motherboard replacement is a common fix, and 3 months is probably long enough to verify that it didn't come with somebody else's problem that wasn't fixed.  Laptops are a lot more delicate than desktops, and tend to get a lot more handling and exposure to risks.  Often, by 4 or 5 years, you are replacing it component by component.  At some point, you'll decide it isn't cost-effective to repair, by which time you might have almost paid for a new computer in repair costs to keep old tech alive.

Comment: (Cont'd)  The decision has to be based on the laptop's current condition, age, adequacy, and your finances.  Older than about 5 yrs, I'd think twice about more than a trivial repair.  Older than about 3-4 yrs, I'd buy a new one rather than repair at more than half the cost of a new one.  Less than 4 yrs and in generally good condition and adequate, I'd probably repair if less than 20-25% of the cost of a new one.  Everything else is a gray area, with many things to consider.